# How to make div bottom

Tags: html, css, google-web-designer

I dont know how to name this topic properly.

When i set `position:absolute;` to the div,and set `bottom:0;` my div content goes to end of the page

I want to know how to make that div go to the end of the div In which it is located.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use 0 for bottom property because if it is then your content may be get off because HTML inline is vertical not horizontal so you will not be able to see your if bottom is 0.

I am not at bottom